# Error: URI already taken

Tags: slug

I've got a content type for team members but whenever I try to add one it gives me an error saying "the URI 'team' has already been taken".

I assume the URI is made from the slug, which is where I get the error.
The title of the team members is made automatically from the first name and last name.

And even when I type in the slug myself it keeps giving the same error. What's weird is that I was able to create one team member successfully but it started failing afterwards.

URI error:
[image: URI Error]

Title settings:
[image: Content type auto title]

Comment: What's in your team section's URL format setting? It should probably be "team/{slug}", though I'm guessing it's currently only "team".

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff omg, I feel so dumb right now. Yes, it was just team. I knew it would've been something small like this, but your comment helped me out a lot, thank you.

Comment: Haha, no worries - it's the little things that trip you up. Happy you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'm writing this in case someone comes across the same problem)

As @MatsMikkelRummelhoff pointed out, I still had to change the URL's format settings to team/{slug}